# gcc weak attribute inconsistent behaviour

Tags: c, gcc, linker, truestudio

I am using gcc compiler in windows10's powershell. gcc came with the Atollic TrueSTUDIO ide. The reason I am doing this is to be able to create an .exe file from the C code so unit testing becomes easier.

I encounter a linker error (undefined reference to 'function_name') when there is a function that is defined as weak and that function is used in another .c file.

Meanwhile I do not get this linker error if I use arm-atollic-eabi-gcc or gcc running on ubuntu.

Here is a simple code to demonstrate this:

hello.c:

```
#include "weak.h"
void whatever(void)
{
  iamweak();
}
```

weak.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "weak.h"

void __attribute__((weak)) iamweak(void)
{
    printf("i am weak...\n");
}
```

weak.h

```
void iamweak(void);
```

main.c

```
int main(void)
{
 return 0;
}
```

Creating the object files and linking:

> > gcc -c main.c weak.c hello.c
>
> > gcc -o main.exe main.o weak.o hello.o
>
> > hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `iamweak'
>     collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Now I checked with gcc-nm the symbol table of hello.o:

> > gcc-nm hello.o
>
> 00000000 b .bss
>
> 00000000 d .data
>
> 00000000 r .eh_frame
>
> 00000000 r .rdata$zzz
>
> 00000000 t .text
>
> U _iamweak
>
> 00000000 T _whatever

Symbol table for weak.o:

> >gcc-nm weak.o
>
> 00000000 b .bss
>
> 00000000 d .data
>
> 00000000 r .eh_frame
>
> 00000000 r .rdata
>
> 00000000 r .rdata$zzz
>
> 00000000 t .text
>
> 00000000 T .weak._iamweak.
>
> w _iamweak
>
> U _puts

Now when I use gcc on Ubuntu as I said everything works. Also the symbol tables are a little different.

Symbol table for hello.o:

> nm hello.o
>
> U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
>
> U iamweak
>
> 0000000000000000 T whatever

Symbol table for weak.o:

> nm weak.o
>
> U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
>
> 0000000000000000 W iamweak
>
> U puts

From https://linux.die.net/man/1/nm it says that "If lowercase, the symbol is local; if uppercase, the symbol is global (external)."

So iamweak is local in windows10 and global in Ubuntu. Is that why the linker cannot see it? What can I do about this? The weak function definitions are also in some HAL libraries and I don't want to modify those. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Try to use this other kind of syntax `// function declaration

int __attribute__((weak)) power2(int x);

  // or

int power2(int x) __attribute__((weak));

// variable declaration;
extern int __attribute__((weak)) global_var;` (They are explanation lines terminated by ;)

Comment: I use attolic studio for years and I do not see anything like this

Comment: @P__J__ Have you actually tried what I described?

Comment: @SirJoBlack I don't want the declarations to be weak, only the function definitions.

Comment: Does gcc even support weak symbols on non-ELF platforms? The gcc [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) says nothing about it: "Weak symbols are supported for ELF targets, and also for a.out targets when using the GNU assembler and linker"

Comment: Windows binaries are using the PE format, very different from ELF.

Answer (score 0):

it is atollic gcc fork error. It does even worse:

```
          main:
00401440:   push    %ebp
00401441:   mov     %esp,%ebp
00401443:   and     $0xfffffff0,%esp
00401446:   call    0x401970 <__main>
36          iamweak();
0040144b:   call    0x0
37          return 0;
00401450:   mov     $0x0,%eax
38        }
```

the complete atollic studio project [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3cfd67b807f9bf5d711d89c0f73d20d020200129113119/6bb58efdde904a4c1c74ad89f3d4d91f20200129113119/2082e4)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this. I am not sure if I understand though. The call 0x0 shouldn't be there? Does this mean that the weak attribute is not supported on windows binaries?

Comment: they are supported - it is just a bug (IMO) in the atollic PC toolchain. For the windows PC stuff just use recent version of mingw

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting the same error with mingw :\